# How to quickly & easily toggle touchpad on and off on a windows 10 laptop?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, keyboard-shortcuts, touchpad

I am wondering if there's a way to easily toggle the touch-pad on and off on a windows 10 computer that doesn't have a location on that can be tapped to do that action (upper left corner of the touch pad). What I consider easy is:

- A sequence of 1-3 keys that can be pressed. (Ideal)
- A specific swipe on the touch-pad.
- Something that can be typed as a command to Cortana.
- Downloading a software that could do the job when sequence is pressed to activate it and to deactivate it.

I have found softwares like *Touchpad blocker* but, they only start working when key are pressed, this makes sense but, sometimes I stop typing and I don't want my touch pad to come back on

I am aware that there are questions that are similar to this but, they haven't provided me with an answer.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: There's a PowerShell script that you could modify at https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/8hrk45/powershell_script_to_automatically_disable_the/

Comment: What does powershell do?

Comment: PowerShell is a scripting language that comes with Windows.

Comment: @DrMoishe you mean PowerShell is the CLI that surrounds the Kernel

Answer (score -2):

Yes, there is. From my experience, every time I bought a laptop, I had to press a key combination to enable or disable the touchpad. (`Fn+F9` for my current laptop). Moreover, the touchpad drivers come with a program which resides in the Systray which also allows the user to enable or disable the touchpad). So, in my opinion, what you are asking for is an overkill.

Comment: What do you mean by "Systray".

Also, the "Fn+F9" isn't working; if I'm on a webpage it will cause the search bar to be selected but, not disable the touch-pad.

Comment: Oh sorry. The Systray is the Notification Area, in Windows 10. In earlier versions, it was names The System Tray, or Systray. Fn+F9 is at my laptop (an Asus). For yours, it can be another combination.

Comment: I can't upvote this answer enough!! Just what I was looking for (Fn + F5 for me, just oook at the sysmbols on the Fn keys). OP, did you ever get an answer? @BogdanDoicin thanx a 1,000,000

Comment: You're welcome @MawgsaysreinstateMonica

Comment: I see from your profile that you use Delphi. I asked my partner for Delphi 1 for xmas when it first came out :-)  If learning Python, please use [PyCHram](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=windows) as your IDE. The community version is free, even for commercial use. I use it both at home and professionally, and know of nothing better (I _have_ looked).  I recommend Udemy's [00 Days of Code - From Beginner to Professional Python Developer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i3-PQ4CkU8s) by Dr. Angela Yu. Her Flutter course is also excellent. Happy Pythoning :-)

Comment: Fn functions and systray icons are unfortunately vendor specifc. My DELL laptop and drivers don't have this option for example.